# Removing elements from mongoengine queryset

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

After I query the database and get the objects in a queryset I want to do some manipulation on the objects like changing field values, removing items from embedded document lists etc. . On this occasion I am not interested in saving those changes to db so I am using mongoengine kind of like a parser. I want to loop over the objects in a queryset, manipulate them and to some filtering on the queryset. But I can't remove elements from the queryset. And even if I could changes I make to objects in a queryset are not reflected to the queryset as queryset returns copies if you loop over them etc.
Is there a way to do it? Or I am open to suggestions for any other tools.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.